# How to symlinking multiple directories

Tags: docker, symfony, symlink

My project exists of 3 symfony 'apps'.

a public env, a private env and a shared env.

The shared env. is located in the vendor map both in the public and private env.

Right now if i change something in the shared env while i'm working in the public env i need to copy this vendor directory to my shared env directory so i can save the changes. The goal is that if i change something in the private or public env in the shared env it will change on the other places too.

File structure:

Directory:

1. (dir)Public

   - APP/
   - VENDOR/

     - **shared**
2. (dir)**Shared**

   - APP/
3. (dir)Private

   - APP/
   - VENDOR/

     - **shared**

**GOAL**

change something in **public/vendor/shared** results in changing it in **Shared** folder and in **Private/vendor/shared** visa versa

Comment: What's your exact question? Why not implement these symlinks? How is this related to Docker or Symfony?

Comment: use the symfony structure. Using docker as hosting these projects.